# How to use a button to within a app to display the phone's contact list

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Hello everyone I am completely new to programing no experience at all so please treat me as a 2 year old when you respond. I have alot of time on my hands as I sit in an office with nothing to do so I figure I should do something productive, and since I have a android tablet I figure I'll try to learn how to make apps for it. This is my first attempt and I'm getting an error in the .java portion of the code, I've been reading and reading on various sites and can't seem to get a clear understanding of what I need to do to correct it. PLEASE HELP

Now down to business, in the app I am trying to learn how to display an image its that simple, I'm taking baby steps. So I started a project, read a few tutorials on how to code ImageView and then I got stuck. **I have the error that says "The public type TestImages must be defined in its own file" so I ask how to define/create this file? where to put it?**

Here is the .java portion of the code where the error lies.

```
  package com.example.myproject;


  import com.example.myproject.util.SystemUiHider;

  import android.annotation.TargetApi;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Build;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.os.Handler;
  import android.view.MotionEvent;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.ImageView;

  public class TestImages extends Activity {

    /**Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
    }
   }
```

Please help, and if you know of any other resource out there that can help a newbie/dummy like myself who don't know anything about coding and need every detail explained please point me in that direction. I've tried the Android Developers site but the information presented on there are not explained in detail it looks as if they expects everyone who tries to do this have a background in coding and I don't. Oh and please don't discourge encourage, because I'm eager to learn.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! What is the name of the `.java` file in which you put `TestImages`?

Comment: I didn't place anything in any .java file, I am tring to figure out what TestImage is suppose to be and where to put it. Is it an image?

Answer (score 0):

use on click listener on the button and then check this
https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts

Comment: I didn't place anything in any .java file, I am tring to figure out what TestImage is suppose to be and where to put it. Is it an image?

Comment: check your layout file "activity_fullscreen", do u have the image which have the id test_image ?

Comment: This is what the ImageView seciton looks like   <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/test_image"
                android:src="@drawable/test_image" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"